# How to set permissions for portlets in liferay programmatically?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need an answer. I created User Groups and Roles with the help of **"RoleLocalServiceUtil"** and **"UserGroupLocalServiceUtil"**.

Now I want to set custom portlet permissions to custom roles. For example I want some role to have only view permissions on portlet with name"portletName_1", and another have all avaliable permissions on "portletName_2".

I think I should use **"ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil"** , but don't have an idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: Quite a broad question. Please go through https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/configuring-your-permissions-scheme and come back with a more specific question if there's something still unclear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have changed the markup for the keywords, this jars less to the eye.  I don't know what "portlet" is.  Did you mean "PORTAL" ?

Also, please show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `ResourcePermissionServiceUtil.addResourcePermission()`.

> Now I want to set custom portlet permissions to custom roles. For example I want some role to have only view permissions on portlet with name"portletName_1", and another have all avaliable permissions on "portletName_2".

e.g.

```
ResourcePermissionServiceUtil.addResourcePermission(groupId, companyId, portletID, ResourceConstants.SCOPE_GROUP, groupId, roleId, ActionKeys.VIEW);
```

This will assign "view" permission for the "roleId" for the portlet "portletID" within the scope of the "groupId", means users having role "roleId" will be able to view the portlet "portletID" anywhere within the site whose id is "groupId".

Likewise you can assign other pemissions also. You can use `ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions()` to assign permissions for more than one action at a time.